# How to mock ElasticSearch NEST's GetAsync

Tags: c#, moq, nest

I'm trying to get one document from my ElasticSearch instance using `GetAsync`. I do it something like this

```
var document= await client.GetAsync<MyDocument>("documentId");
return document.Source;
```

I'd like to mock out this call in a unit test. I tried doing something like this

```
[Fact]
public async Task TestGetDocument_ExpectSuccess()
{
    var mockDocument = new Mock<IGetResponse<MyDocument>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        mockDocument
            .Setup(r => r.Source)
            .Returns(_myDocument);
    var mockClient = new Mock<IElasticClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        mockClient
            .Setup(client => client.GetAsync(
                _documentId,
                It.IsAny<Func<GetDescriptor<MyDocument>, IGetRequest>>(),
                It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(mockDocument.Object);
    // ...
}
```

But when I do that, the instantiation of `mockClient` gives this error

```
'ISetup<IElasticClient, Task<GetResponse<MyDocument>>>' does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync' and the best extension method overload 'SequenceExtensions.ReturnsAsync<IGetResponse<MyDocument>>(ISetupSequentialResult<Task<IGetResponse<MyDocument>>>, IGetResponse<MyDocument>)' requires a receiver of type 'ISetupSequentialResult<Task<IGetResponse<MyDocument>>>' [Foo.Bar.ElasticSearch.UnitTests]csharp(CS1929)
```

I'm confused by the `SequenceExtensions` bit in the error since I'm not using `SetupSequence` (if that's what it is referring to). I tried changing the `responseMock` type to `GetResponse<ElasticHitContainer>`, and it gets rid of the compile error, but now I cannot properly mock out the return value of `Source` since I'm not using an interface.

Anyone know how I can get around this?

Comment: Ended up creating an instance of `GetResponse`, and setting the `Source` via reflection. But I'd much prefer to do it a cleaner way without needing to wrap everything with my own interfaces

Comment: Also wondering about this. Having the same issue. Commenting to bump.